# Selecting feature programmatically from GeoJSON using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I am working on a project that uses OpenLayers (version 2.14)to display a Bing layer(GeoJSON format), I have no problem reading the GeoJSON and display features, but I want to select a feature programmatically, for example, there is a table displaying all the features attributes(GeoJSON format.sample:

> {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
>   {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-7923751.4232522,5233536.7371399]},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}
>   ], }

), when I click a row from the table, I want to select or highlight a specific feature on the map using the GEOJSON data in that row.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the method "getFeaturesByAttribute"

or iterate through all features:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < yourgeojsonlayer.features.length; i++) { 
    if(yourgeojsonlayer.features[i].attributes.searchedAttribute == 'searchedValue')
     { selectFeatureControl.select(yourgeojsonlayer.features[i]); break; } 
    }
```

Ps: makes necessary to create a select control first and assign the variable name you use in the for loop (here selectFeatureControl)

I just wrote down a quick example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/sh9wv4m7/

Comment: Imagine ,i clicked on table and get Following geojson :
var featurejson=
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [
{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-7923751.4232522,5233536.7371399]},"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}}}
    ],
};

Comment: vlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable");
    map.addLayer(vlayer); 
 geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
                geojson_format.ignoreExtraDims = true;
                
  var ft = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geojson_format.read(featuredata),{scientific_name:'hydro'}); 
                 vlayer.addFeatures([ft]);

var features = vlayer.features;
  var selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vlayer, {multiple: true,toggle: false});
                window.map.addControl(selectControl);
                selectControl.activate();

Comment: selectFeature.select(vlayer.getFeatureBy('scientific_name', 'hydro'));

Comment: I do that,but it is not working.Can you help me ,how can I do that with "getFeatureBy" or "getFeaturesByAttribute"

Comment: i added a example in my answer above

Comment: thanks,but this not with geojson..and i don't know wher is coming city name?

Comment: it's the same syntax with your geojson layer. just check vlayer.features[0].attributes to inspect your attributes in your console

Comment: just post your code here at stackexchange or jsfilldle so others can also help you or benefit from an answer that's found

Comment: please look at this..
http://jsfiddle.net/xv6feg0n/1/

Comment: your geojson did not contain any attributes and was not valid,too. please always check with http://geojsonlint.com/ or use something like geojson.io .here the proper code: http://jsfiddle.net/3p5q0ybh/ medford selectet

Comment: please check next question: 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175839/why-doesnt-show-feature-on-map