# why doesn't show feature on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, clustering

this is fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ismayil1993/whwjusob/).Feature doesn't show on map when it has been like this code :

```
 var featureVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: featureClusterSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});
```

But i change source - featureClusterSource to featureVectorSource.it works well but in this time i don't get feature when i click feature on map .

```
 var featureVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: featureVectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});
```

How do I show feature on map with featureClusterSource?

Comment: featureClusterSource will work only if holds points. For polygons or linestring will not work. Didnt get your click problem. Changing to `featureVectorSource` will log the feature in the console when click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your code. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/whwjusob/4/

First try to "beautify" your code with tools like http://jsbeautifier.org/ in order that it becomes better readible.

Your problem was that you tried to insert as source a cluster with a vector but no olCollection.

```
var featureVectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
var featureClusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({

    source: featureVectorSource,
});
var featureVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: featureClusterSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});
```

I changed it to this and now it works:

```
var features = new ol.Collection();

var featureSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features
});

var featureVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: featureSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 2
        }),
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffcc33'
            })
        })
    })
});
```